# readOGR point shapefile and plot using Leaflet > NULL values in LON/LAT

Tags: r, leaflet, geocoding, shapefile

Could someone please advise me on how to proceed in the following: I have a ESRI shapefile from a town in the Netherlands (Urk) and what to plot every housenummer on a map with a marker. Leaflet provides an error saying the file has NULL values, but I can't seem to find them.

```
# what does this file look like
> ogrInfo("WGS1984_Urk/nummer.shp", "nummer")

Source: "WGS1984_Urk/nummer.shp", layer: "nummer"
Driver: ESRI Shapefile; number of rows: 7792 
Feature type: wkbPoint with 2 dimensions
Extent: (5.591987 52.64994) - (170059.4 518956.2)
LDID: 87 
Number of fields: 18 
         name type length typeName
1   NUMMER_ID    4     16   String
2  STRAATNAAM    4     80   String
3  HUISNUMMER    0      8  Integer
......

# Read ESRI shapefiles into R
> huisnummers_Urk <-readOGR(dsn="WGS1984_Urk/nummer.shp", 
                          layer="nummer", verbose = TRUE, 
                          dropNULLGeometries= TRUE,
                          p4s = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs")


# Info from spdplyr package
> huisnummers_Urk

class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 7792 
extent      : 5.591987, 170059.4, 52.64994, 518956.2  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs 
variables   : 18
# A tibble: 7,792 × 18

# Plot house in Leaflet
> leaflet(huisnummers_Urk) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(lng = huisnummers_Urk$x1, lat = huisnummers_Urk$x2)

Error in validateCoords(lng, lat, funcName) : 
  addMarkers requires non-NULL longitude/latitude values

# Where are the missing values?
> huisnummers_Urk@coords[!complete.cases(huisnummers_Urk@coords),]
 coords.x1 coords.x2
```

Where should I start to see what I am doing wrong here? I've put all the coords in a matrix for inspection and see no NA's / NULL's.

Answer (score 0):

I've found two errors: one in the code and one in the dataset.

1) The Leaflet command for lng and lat should point to "huisnummers_Urk$coords.x1". The name of the coordinates *slot* is also "coords" and this is repeated in de column. So I made the mistake of leaving this part out.

2) There are lng / lat values of the chart, you can filter them by using the spdplyr package:

```
huisnummer_urk <- huisnummer_urk %>%  
filter(huisnummer_urk$coords.x1 >= -90, 
huisnummer_urk$coords.x1 <= 90,  huisnummer_urk$coords.x2 >= -180,  huisnummer_urk$coords.x2 <= 180)
```